Did Jiraiya love Tsunade?
I would like to know if Jiraiya had feelings for Tsunade. Did he like her?
I have seen Did Tsunade like jiraya? that discusses their relationship, mentioning that Tsunade didn't like Jiraiya, but I don't know Jiraiya's feelings for Tsunade.

@Dimitrimx Did Tsunade like Jiraiya? doesn't appear to be a duplicate of this question. Tsunade liking (or not liking) Jiraiya doesn't necessarily mean that Jiraiya reciprocates those feelings.

While Jiraiya does think that Tsunade is a very beautiful woman, but he already knows that Tsunade is in love with Dan Kato even though Dan Kato is dead. So Jiraiya and Tsunade only like each other as friends.

Turns out it didn't matter anyway because Jiraiya ended up dead.
